# Need bgsound for mobile websites

Tags: javascript, html

I had used an audio file as background sound for my website, It is working fine in desktop, but not playing in the mobiles. Is there any way to playing an audio file for mobile also, please provide me a necessary solution for this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Audio/Video auto-play is not supported in all mobile browsers for their own reasons.You have to wait for user interaction (touch, click, etc. events) in order to start playing audio..

Comment: I hate background sound, don't use them!!

Comment: @LiYinKong, Its not about you like it or not! It depends on the requirement of the app..

Comment: This is a personal webpage,
<audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="MaateManthramu.ogg">
      <source src="MaateManthramu.mp3">
</audio>
this is the code i am using, in web it is working fine, but need to play on the mobiles also.